# StackExchange.Redis: несколько вопросов по транзакциям

Tags: c#, .net, redis

Возникло несколько вопросов по работе транзакций в StackExchange.Redis:

1. Можно ли помещать в одну транзакцию команды, предназначенные для разных нод в кластере? Например, у ключа первой команды хэштэг `{1}`, а у ключа второй команды -- `{2}`. (Подозреваю, что нельзя.)
2. В каких случаях вызов `Execute()`/`ExecuteAsync()` возвращает `false`? Только когда установленные условия не были выполнены? Может ли вызов вернуть `false`, если условия вообще не были установлены?
3. Eсли происходит ошибка сети или внутренняя ошибка Redis, то вызов `Execute()`/`ExecuteAsync()` выбросит исключение или вернет `false`? Нужно ли еще проверять таски всех команд (предполагается, что все команды корректные и не должны выбрасывать ошибок) или они просто будут в состоянии cancelled?

К сожалению, [документация](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/docs/Transactions.md) насчет #2 и #3 не слишком подробная.

---

[Этот вопрос -- дубликат с enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48711230/1985167).

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48711230/1548895

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я заглянул в исходники StackExchange.Redis, а также поигрался с драйвером, и вот что обнаружил:

- при вызове методов команд у `ITransaction` никакого общения с сервером не происходит
- драйвер обращается к Redis только после вызова `Execute()`/`ExecuteAsync()`

Поэтому ответы следующие:

1. Как [подсказали](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48743635/1985167) в оригинальном вопросе на enSO, в случае кластера все multi-key команды должны соответствовать одному слоту. В контексте кластера транзакция считается multi-key командой.

> Redis Cluster implements all the single key commands available in the
>   non-distributed version of Redis. Commands performing complex
>   multi-key operations like Set type unions or intersections are
>   implemented as well as long as the keys all belong to the same node.

https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec

При попытке выполнить транзакцию с невалидными ключами получим исключение "Multi-key operations must involve a single slot".

2. `Execute()`/`ExecuteAsync()` возвращает `false` в двух случаях: когда условия транзакции не были выполнены и транзакция была отменена, и когда драйвер не смог поставить команду в очередь (например, если на сервере кончилась память). Все таски при этом помечаются как canceled. Также `Execute()`/`ExecuteAsync()` **не** возвращает `false` если некоторые команды завершились неудачно (например, если команда была адресована ключу с неправильным типом значения).
3. В случае проблем с сетью, `Execute()`/`ExecuteAsync()` выбрасывает исключение, а все таски остаются в состоянии waiting for activation.

Итого, таски следует проверять только когда `Execute()`/`ExecuteAsync()` возвращает `true`: каждый таск будет содержать или результат команды, или ошибку (см. свойство `Exception`).