# C# межпроцессное взаимодействие?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service

Есть две windows-службы, написанные на C#. Первая служит wcf-сервисом для клиентов и обрабатывает всю бизнес-логику. Вторая же предполагается просто как хранилище данных, условного кеша из БД. Вопрос в том, как реализовать быстрый забор данных первой службе из второй? 
Простой вариант - средствами wcf,но есть мнение что можно проиграть в скорости. Какие есть еще удобные варианты?

Comment: "но есть мнение что можно проиграть в скорости": мнению доверять не стоит, возьмите и померяйте. Я вот не знаю, что будет быстрее: сходить в базу MSSQL за громоздким объектом или сходить в WCF службу за кешем этого же рассчитанного объекта. Но вообще, я бы пожалуй сто раз подумал на тему, а нужен ли вообще этот кеширующий сервис. А раз вы обходитесь без профилировщика, а тыкаете наугад - то легко ухудшить архитектуру из благих побуждений. Цифры, цифры где? Сначала сделали кеш "наверное, может тормозить", потом думаем "а не слишком ли кеш медленный" - и всё это без точных замеров, Карл!

Comment: Неверно все понимаете. Кеш нужен. Сейчас кеш висит в первой же службе, что очень неудобно, потому что при каждом перезапуске службы кеш поднимается минут пять. Хочется отделить кеш от основной службы именно из-за этого. И да, замеры делались - с кешем, и без кеша напрямую из базы. И замеры отправки наших данных по wcf делались. Так что очень жду ответов по теме

Comment: Можно попробовать именнованные пайпы. [Пример с MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb546085(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Удобный - субъективное понятие.

Я бы на вашем месте взял Redis для кэша + StackExchange.Redis со стороны службы/потребителя. И использовал protobuf-net для сериализации.

Если процесс заселения кэша при этом остается сложным, и хочется отделить его от основной службы - выносите его в отдельный сервис, который будет заниматься только запихиванием обновленных данных в redis.

Comment: Оффтоп: видели: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/782857/10105?

Comment: @VladD видел. мне хватило двух недель дебага проблем соединения StackExchange.Redis с Azure Redis, я в этот адский код без острой необходимости не полезу :)